# AngularJS ng-keypress not triggering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m having some problems while trying to implement ng-keypress in AngularJS. I already looked at another post´s here but still can´t make it work.

Here is my HTML code:

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
<div ng-controller="GameController">
<div id="chatZone"> 
        <form action="#" method="get" id="id_form_chat">
            <input type="text" id="m" autocomplete="off"  ng-model="chatMsg" ng-ng-keypress="keyPressMsg($event)">
        </form>

        <ul id="messages"><li ng-repeat="m in chatMessages track by $index">@{{m}}</li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection('content')
```

My Angular code:

```
(function(){
"use strict";   
var module = angular.module('memoryGame', []);

function GameController($scope, $http, $timeout) {
        $scope.keyPressMsg = function($event){
        console.log("success");
        };

}module.controller('GameController', ['$scope', '$http','$timeout',       GameController]);
})();
```

EDIT1:
Sorry guys the problem is when i change text in the input box the function in my controller doesn´t trigger itself..
I have edited both angular and html code if u could take a look i would be greatfull

I dont catch anything on console

EDIT2: Solved sorry was misspelling a word..

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is, but this code works correctly when added to a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0SvW0J1FnEOmYrkCmGE9?p=preview) including just a basic angular module and controller.  pressing 'Enter' definitely triggers the success.  If this is not working in your code, you may need to provide more information.

Comment: @Claies sorry for not expressing myself well if u could take another look at my code and help me figured out what the problem is i would be greatfull.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the pressed key code by `$event.which` so change `$event.keyCode == 13` to `$event.which === 13` and your problem is solved

Comment: sorry for not explaning myself correctly.. The problem is that my function dont trigger when i write in my input box

Comment: Well that's probably because you're using the `ng-ng-keypress` directive instead of `ng-keypress` directive.

Comment: omg thanks.. and sorry i was doing some copy/paste´s and didn´t notice..
it was that ..